# Adding constructor to third party class/struct definition

Tags: c++

A third party library has structs defined as

```
typedef struct _Example
{
  int member;
} Example;
```

As a side question, just out of interest, why that definition? Why not `struct Example { ... }`?

Anyhow, I want to serialize the information with boost::serialization, and for that need a constructor. Is it safe to just change my version of the 3rd party header file by adding a constructor to the struct definition? Or alternatively, to just copy that definition to my own code base, rename it, add a constructor, and reinterpret_cast to it?

I assume it would be because as I understand functions and constructors shouldn't change the underlying byte layout of the class/struct, is this correct?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you need a constructor?

Comment: @Andreas: Maybe I am misunderstanding, but in [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/serialization/example/demo.cpp) is the following comment: _// every serializable class needs a constructor_

Comment: If you do not provide a constructor a default will be added by the compiler.

Comment: @Cookie: the comment is misleading, it should read: *//every serializable class must be default constructible*. This struct is, so no issue here.

Comment: @Cookie: no problem, as I said the commend is certainly misleading...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your struct has a constructor. Compiler generated for you a no-arg constructor and thats exactly what boost::serialization needs.

Answer (score 4):

It's better to derive from that struct and define all the constructors you need. Modifying third-party libraries and copy-pasting definitions is not a good idea.

`typedef struct` pattern comes from C. In [older?] C, `struct _Something` does not allow you to use `_Something` as a type:

```
//_Something x;//not allowed
struct _Something x; //ok
```

With typedef, one can define variables in natural `Something x` way, without that `struct` burden.

Answer (score 3):

The `typedef struct ...` is derives from `C` and not `C++` to use shorthands for `struct`s. Is it possible that the 3rd party library is written in C?

I wouldn't suggest using reinterpret_casts like you are trying. I suggest you create a small wrapper class to encapsulate the `Example` struct. This is safer and can spare you a lot of debugging pain.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

```
Why not struct Example { ... } ?
```

`struct Example {...};` is the way how you should define a `struct` in C++, while the `typedef` form is old C-style.

```
functions and constructors shouldn't change the underlying byte layout of the 
class/struct
```

That depends. Functions are stored separated with your data in *text section*. So adding a normal function won't affect the size and layout of your `struct`. However, if there is any `virtual` functions, a "hidden" VPTR will be added in your class. Thus the layout could be very different from that w/o virtual functions.

```
Is it safe to just change my version of the 3rd party header file by adding a 
constructor to the struct definition? Or alternatively, to just copy that definition
to my own code base, rename it, add a constructor, and reinterpret_cast to it?
```

I strongly recommend you ***not*** to copy the definition. That's a very bad idea, especially when that is 3rd-party class out of your control. What if they change its definition one day? There are several ways that you can handle it. E.g., either use aggregation or inheritance. Actually, in this case I think the use of aggregation excels.

```
// The layout of this struct is the same as
// that of struct Example
struct MyExample
{
   Example m_ex;
   MyExample(int member)
   {
      m_ex.member = member;
   }
   //..
};
```